# Eilenberg-Mac Lane and classifying spaces

Tags: homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces

What can we say about

> An Eilenberg-Mac Lane space $K(G,n)$ is a classifying space $BG$.

When it could be true?

For what kind of $G$?

For what values of $n$?

References are welcomed.

Comment: For a topological group $G$, I remember that $BG$ is an Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(G,1)$. Also, I have not read through the whole thing, but maybe http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/calgary/BG.html would be useful.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar, thanks. I'm looking for the other direction.

Comment: Not quite. For a discrete group $G$, $BG = K(G,1)$, but for example, $S^1 = K(\mathbb Z, 1)$ and so $BS^1 = K(\mathbb Z, 2)$.

Answer (score 1):

In general for a group $G$, we have $\Omega BG \simeq G$. Thus, $BG= K(H,n)$ if and only if $G = K(H, n-1)$. That is to say, a necessary and sufficent condition is that $G$ itself is an Eilenberg-Maclane space.